# Material-Ui - Type 'BottomNavigationProps' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, create-react-app

I have updated my version of material-ui this evening and am now receiving the blow error:

```
C:/Working/boom-repository/boom-web-app/node_modules/@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation/BottomNavigation.d.ts
(4,18): Interface 'BottomNavigationProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & StyledComponentProps<"root"> & { className?: string | undefined;...'.
  Type 'BottomNavigationProps' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'onChange' are incompatible.
      Type '((event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: any) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((event: FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void) | undefined'.
        Type '(event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: any) => void' is not assignable to type '((event: FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void) | undefined'.
          Type '(event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void'.
```

I am on TS 3.0.1.

I have performed a npm upgrade on all packages, clean the node_modules and reinstalled a couple of times now. I have found similar issues online but have not been able to find a solution so any advice would be great.

My question: is anyone aware of versioning issues or the like that may cause this?

My packages.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "boom-web-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^2.0.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "pubnub-react": "^1.2.0",
    "qs": "^6.5.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-app-rewire-provide-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.5.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.0",
    "react-block-ui": "^1.1.2",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-drag-sortable": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.3.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-redux": "^3.1.0",
    "react-redux-toastr": "^7.4.0",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.12.0",
    "react-scrollbar": "^0.5.4",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.8",
    "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
    "react-stars": "^2.2.5",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.16",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.2",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.20.1",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "recharts": "^1.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sweetalert-react": "^0.4.11",
    "typesafe-actions": "^1.1.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/content/scss/main.scss -o src/content/css",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/content/scss/main.scss -o src/content/css --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-app-rewired start --scripts-version react-scripts-ts",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-app-rewired build --scripts-version react-scripts-ts",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "unit": "set CI=true&&react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.28",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
    "@types/react-redux": "^5.0.21"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost"
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  Please post your `tsconfig.json`, or (even better) a repository that reproduces the problem.